# Overlapping Accesses pointer

Tags: swift, pointers, swift4

I'm trying to run `swix` in Swift 4. I've solved most of the initial issues that came up but there's one left I don't know enough about to resolve. It's three instances of the same error, see code bellow

```
var nc = __CLPK_integer(N)
dgetrf_(&nc, &nc, !y, &nc, &ipiv, &info)
```

> Overlapping accesses to 'nc', but modification requires exclusive
>   access; consider copying to a local variable

Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a consequence of [SE-0176 Enforce Exclusive Access to Memory](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md), which was implemented in **Swift 4:**
The `__m`, `__n`, and `__lda` arguments of `dgetrf_()`have the type
`UnsafeMutablePointer<>`, even though the pointed-to variable is not mutated (but the compiler does not know that!) and 
you pass the address of the same variable `nc` to all three of them.

There are two possible solutions: Additional variable copies:

```
var nc1 = nc, nc2 = nc
dgetrf_(&nc, &nc1, &matrix, &nc2, &ipiv, &info)
```

Or `withUnsafeMutablePointer`, because unsafe pointers do not use any active enforcement:

```
withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &nc) {
    dgetrf_($0, $0, &matrix, $0, &ipiv, &info)
}
```